# Observable.Create and Observer Disposal

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am trying to understand when I use

```
    Observable.just(1).subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {

        Disposable disposable;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
            System.out.println("Subscribed");
            this.disposable = disposable;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println(integer);
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Complete");
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }
    })
```

After `OnComplete` or `OnError`, `disposable.isDisposed()` returns true where as when I use

```
  Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Integer> observableEmitter) throws Exception {
            if (!observableEmitter.isDisposed())
                observableEmitter.onComplete();
        }
    }).subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {

        Disposable disposable;

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable disposable) {
            System.out.println("Subscribed");
            this.disposable = disposable;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println(integer);
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Complete");
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }
    });
```

I see `disposable.isDisposed()` returns false. Can someone explain me what really is happening ?. I understand a well written Observable.create must not emit items after `onComplete()` or `onError()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Disposable` just holds an reference to `subscription`, in order to dispose it you need to call `disposable.dispose()`, `Observable` wont dispose `Disposable` instance on complete method.

```
 @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Complete");
            disposable.dispose();
            System.out.println(disposable.isDisposed());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally, `isDisposed` was meant to indicate `dispose` was called. Since `onError` and `onComplete` don't call `dispose` by default, you don't usually get `isDisposed` true after termination. The Reactive Streams specification states that a subscription should be considered cancelled when `onError` and `onComplete` is called, which means no actual code (thus overhead) is necessary to be present in implementations.

Unfortunately, people started using it as completion indicator outside a flow (i.e., to see if a particular `subscribe()` has reached its terminal state). I don't recommend relying on `isDisposed` (outside `Disposable` containers) because it conflates the async reaction to completion with a possibly synchronous (and blocking) waiting for completion.

In your particular case, the `disposable` will indicate `isDisposed` after `onComplete` has returned, so an outside view would indicate `isDisposed` true.